# How to extract date based on condition over two different variables in R

Tags: r, date, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a dataset of 100 observations which contain patient id,drugcode,prescription date. I want to create a new column "index date" which is the date when the patient changed drug for the third time.

```
PatientID   DrugCode    Prescriptiondate   
A1  3   07-08-2014   
A1  3   08-09-2014   
A1  7   19-09-2014   
A1  5   30-09-2014  
A2  4   11-07-2014  
A2  4   21-07-2014  
A2  3   13-08-2014  
A2  5   26-08-2014  
A2  5   30-09-2014  
A3  2   16-08-2014  
A3  3   17-09-2014  
A4  5   08-06-2014  
A4  5   29-06-2014  
A4  6   20-08-2014  
A4  6   24-09-2014  
A4  4   22-10-2014  
A4  4   25-10-2014
```

The data set should look like this:

```
PatientID   DrugCode    Prescriptiondate    IndexDate  
A1  3   07-08-2014  30-09-2014  
A1  3   08-09-2014  30-09-2014  
A1  7   19-09-2014  30-09-2014  
A1  5   30-09-2014  30-09-2014  
A2  4   11-07-2014  26-08-2014  
A2  4   21-07-2014  26-08-2014  
A2  3   13-08-2014  26-08-2014  
A2  5   26-08-2014  26-08-2014  
A2  5   30-09-2014  26-08-2014  
A3  2   16-08-2014  NA  
A3  3   17-09-2014  NA  
A4  5   08-06-2014  22-10-2014  
A4  5   29-06-2014  22-10-2014  
A4  6   20-08-2014  22-10-2014  
A4  6   24-09-2014  22-10-2014  
A4  4   22-10-2014  22-10-2014  
A4  4   25-10-2014  22-10-2014
```

In the above case,patient A1 & A2 changed the drug third time to drug 5 on 30-09-2014 and 26-08-2014 respectively;A3 have not changed drug third time and A4 has changed to drug 4 on 22-10-2014, so the index date should be 30-09-2014,26-08-2014,NA,22-10-2014 respectively.

Please if anyone can assist in writing the code for such problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a base R solution, shamelessly stealing Pierre Lafortune's brilliant match-unique idea:

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID=c('A1','A1','A1','A1','A2','A2','A2','A2','A2','A3','A3','A4','A4','A4','A4','A4','A4'),DrugCode=c(3,3,7,5,4,4,3,5,5,2,3,5,5,6,6,4,4),Prescriptiondate=as.Date(c('07-08-2014','08-09-2014','19-09-2014','30-09-2014','11-07-2014','21-07-2014','13-08-2014','26-08-2014','30-09-2014','16-08-2014','17-09-2014','08-06-2014','29-06-2014','20-08-2014','24-09-2014','22-10-2014','25-10-2014'),'%d-%m-%Y'));
df$IndexDate <- do.call('c',by(df,df$PatientID,function(g) rep(g$Prescriptiondate[match(unique(g$DrugCode)[3],g$DrugCode)],nrow(g))));
df;
##    PatientID DrugCode Prescriptiondate  IndexDate
## 1         A1        3       2014-08-07 2014-09-30
## 2         A1        3       2014-09-08 2014-09-30
## 3         A1        7       2014-09-19 2014-09-30
## 4         A1        5       2014-09-30 2014-09-30
## 5         A2        4       2014-07-11 2014-08-26
## 6         A2        4       2014-07-21 2014-08-26
## 7         A2        3       2014-08-13 2014-08-26
## 8         A2        5       2014-08-26 2014-08-26
## 9         A2        5       2014-09-30 2014-08-26
## 10        A3        2       2014-08-16       <NA>
## 11        A3        3       2014-09-17       <NA>
## 12        A4        5       2014-06-08 2014-10-22
## 13        A4        5       2014-06-29 2014-10-22
## 14        A4        6       2014-08-20 2014-10-22
## 15        A4        6       2014-09-24 2014-10-22
## 16        A4        4       2014-10-22 2014-10-22
## 17        A4        4       2014-10-25 2014-10-22
```

Comment: I am getting the error message while running the code  "Error in do.call(c, by(df, df$PatientID, function(g) rep(g$Prescriptiondate[match(unique(g$DrugCode)[3],  : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function"

Comment: @Mayur You probably assigned `c` at some point, which masked the `base::c()` function. Fortunately, `do.call()` also accept a character string for the function argument, so `'c'` should work. Please try my edited code and let me know if it works. (Another approach is to qualify it, i.e. `do.call(base::c,...)`.)

Comment: Thanks for help..I am able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>% group_by(PatientID) %>% mutate(IndexDate = Prescriptiondate[match(unique(DrugCode)[3], DrugCode)])
# Source: local data frame [17 x 4]
# Groups: PatientID
# 
#    PatientID DrugCode Prescriptiondate  IndexDate
# 1         A1        3       07-08-2014 30-09-2014
# 2         A1        3       08-09-2014 30-09-2014
# 3         A1        7       19-09-2014 30-09-2014
# 4         A1        5       30-09-2014 30-09-2014
# 5         A2        4       11-07-2014 26-08-2014
# 6         A2        4       21-07-2014 26-08-2014
# 7         A2        3       13-08-2014 26-08-2014
# 8         A2        5       26-08-2014 26-08-2014
# 9         A2        5       30-09-2014 26-08-2014
# 10        A3        2       16-08-2014         NA
# 11        A3        3       17-09-2014         NA
# 12        A4        5       08-06-2014 22-10-2014
# 13        A4        5       29-06-2014 22-10-2014
# 14        A4        6       20-08-2014 22-10-2014
# 15        A4        6       24-09-2014 22-10-2014
# 16        A4        4       22-10-2014 22-10-2014
# 17        A4        4       25-10-2014 22-10-2014
```

I guess it's the same idea with `data.table`

```
dt[, IndexDate := Prescriptiondate[match(unique(DrugCode)[3], DrugCode)], PatientID]
#    PatientID DrugCode Prescriptiondate  IndexDate
#  1:        A1        3       07-08-2014 30-09-2014
#  2:        A1        3       08-09-2014 30-09-2014
#  3:        A1        7       19-09-2014 30-09-2014
#  4:        A1        5       30-09-2014 30-09-2014
#  5:        A2        4       11-07-2014 26-08-2014
#  6:        A2        4       21-07-2014 26-08-2014
#  7:        A2        3       13-08-2014 26-08-2014
#  8:        A2        5       26-08-2014 26-08-2014
#  9:        A2        5       30-09-2014 26-08-2014
# 10:        A3        2       16-08-2014         NA
# 11:        A3        3       17-09-2014         NA
# 12:        A4        5       08-06-2014 22-10-2014
# 13:        A4        5       29-06-2014 22-10-2014
# 14:        A4        6       20-08-2014 22-10-2014
# 15:        A4        6       24-09-2014 22-10-2014
# 16:        A4        4       22-10-2014 22-10-2014
# 17:        A4        4       25-10-2014 22-10-2014
```

`match` works because it stops once it finds a match. So if a drug is used over many days or one, it will not change the outcome. We look for the first instance of the DrugCode changing for the third time. `unique` works because it arranges it's values in the order that they appear. So `unique(x)[3]` will give the third change in that value.

Comment: Thanks for help..I am able to get the desired result.